# How to check which field raised a ValidationError in Django REST Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, tdd

I'm using `self.assertRaisesMessage(rest_framework_exceptions.ValidationError, expected_message)` to test my custom validators. Is there some way to use that or something similar to also **assert which field caused the validation error to be raised?**

The use case is that I have two validators which raise the same error for different fields, and because of the relation between them (start and end date) it's not possible to write a test which will fail before introducing the end date and which will also succeed *for the right reason* after introducing the end date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you assert the error by testing the whole form? Like:

```
class FooSerializer(Serializer):
    start_date = DateField()
    end_date = DateField()

foo = FooSerializer(data={'start_date': '2018-01-01', 'end_date': 'incorrect value'})
self.assertFalse(foo.is_valid())
self.assertNotIn('start_date', foo.errors)
self.assertIn('end_date', foo.errors)
```

Comment: It would be great to do this as a single assertion (`assertRaisesFieldMessage` or something), but yes, this is probably the way to go.